# Program overloading?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, optimization

I have this project that has functions to load different chapters of a book. (Ex. loadChapter1)

My thinking was that I will call the functions to load up every chapter when the app launches. But by the time I am done with the program, there would be a huge amount of chapters. It's only loading up lots of NSStrings.

Would that make the program slow to initialize or even crash the program?

My functions are declared in AppDelegate.h using ( `-(void)loadChapter1` ). The way I call it in AppDelegate.m is using `[self loadChapter1]`.

If this is not a good way, this there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You're better off trying something, seeing if it works well, then making changes (and possibly asking questions here) if it doesn't rather than asking a question like this at the outset. For performance questions in particular, the accepted wisdom is that you shouldn't worry too much about performance (memory and CPU usage) while initially writing a program, but rather should do performance optimizations as needed after you've got the program working.

That said, my first approach to this would be to load each chapter as it's requested. So, don't load all the chapters in the book every time the app launches. Rather, load a chapter when the user turns the page to that chapter or selects it in the table of contents (or whatever applies to your app). That way, you don't waste time and memory loading chapters that before they're actually going to be used.